# Unable to send xml response in drupal custom menu callback function and it results in failure message

Tags: 7

```
function custom_changes_menu(){

   $items['broadbean-jobs'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'custom_changes_broadbean_interface_create_update',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function custom_changes_broadbean_interface_create_update(){
  header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
  return custom_changes_broadbean_interface_create();
}

function custom_changes_broadbean_interface_create(){

    http_response_code(200);              
    $response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <job>
    <success>true</success>
    </job>';
    return $response;

}
```

XML Response expected is as mentioned below
[image]

[image]

I still get failure message and hence response does not seem to be sent properly
When using postman app to test it, the response I get is 
as seen here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" prefix="content: http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/ dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/ foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/ og: http://ogp.me/ns# rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema# sioc: http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns# sioct: http://rdfs.org/sioc/types# skos: http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core# xsd: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
<head>
  <link rel="profile" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.example.com/sites/default/files/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" />
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
@import url("https://www.example.com/modules/system/system.base.css?pem64p");
</style>
<style>
@import url("https://www.example.com/modules/field/theme/field.css?pem64p");
@import url("https://www.example.com/modules/node/node.css?pem64p");
@import url("https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/views/css/views.css?pem64p");
@import url("https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/css/ckeditor.css?pem64p");
</style>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Roboto:400,700" media="all" />
<style>
@import url("https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/ctools/css/ctools.css?pem64p");
</style>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.css" media="all" />
<style>
@import url("https://www.example.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/css/3.0.2/overrides.min.css?pem64p");
@import url("https://www.example.com/sites/all/themes/example/css/style.css?pem64p");
</style>
  <!-- HTML5 element support for IE6-8 -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv-printshiv.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <script src="https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.10/jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2"></script>
<script src="https://www.example.com/misc/jquery.once.js?v=1.2"></script>
<script src="https://www.example.com/misc/drupal.js?pem64p"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/google_analytics/googleanalytics.js?pem64p"></script>
<script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i["GoogleAnalyticsObject"]=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,"script","https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js","ga");ga("create", "UA-70937835-1", {"cookieDomain":"auto"});ga("send", "pageview");</script>
<script>jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"example","theme_token":"shC7kxGGkqtdkbNgLM15MiSaQ876Ge9x0To_I-xoDoM","js":{"sites\/all\/themes\/bootstrap\/js\/bootstrap.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/jquery_update\/replace\/jquery\/1.10\/jquery.min.js":1,"misc\/jquery.once.js":1,"misc\/drupal.js":1,"\/\/cdn.jsdelivr.net\/bootstrap\/3.0.2\/js\/bootstrap.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/google_analytics\/googleanalytics.js":1,"0":1},"css":{"modules\/system\/system.base.css":1,"modules\/field\/theme\/field.css":1,"modules\/node\/node.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/views\/css\/views.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/css\/ckeditor.css":1,"\/\/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com\/font-awesome\/4.3.0\/css\/font-awesome.min.css":1,"\/\/fonts.googleapis.com\/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Roboto:400,700":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/ctools\/css\/ctools.css":1,"\/\/cdn.jsdelivr.net\/bootstrap\/3.0.2\/css\/bootstrap.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/bootstrap\/css\/3.0.2\/overrides.min.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/example\/css\/style.css":1}},"googleanalytics":{"trackOutbound":1,"trackMailto":1,"trackDownload":1,"trackDownloadExtensions":"7z|aac|arc|arj|asf|asx|avi|bin|csv|doc(x|m)?|dot(x|m)?|exe|flv|gif|gz|gzip|hqx|jar|jpe?g|js|mp(2|3|4|e?g)|mov(ie)?|msi|msp|pdf|phps|png|ppt(x|m)?|pot(x|m)?|pps(x|m)?|ppam|sld(x|m)?|thmx|qtm?|ra(m|r)?|sea|sit|tar|tgz|torrent|txt|wav|wma|wmv|wpd|xls(x|m|b)?|xlt(x|m)|xlam|xml|z|zip"},"bootstrap":{"anchorsFix":1,"anchorsSmoothScrolling":1,"formHasError":1,"popoverEnabled":1,"popoverOptions":{"animation":1,"html":0,"placement":"right","selector":"","trigger":"click","triggerAutoclose":1,"title":"","content":"","delay":0,"container":"body"},"tooltipEnabled":1,"tooltipOptions":{"animation":1,"html":0,"placement":"auto left","selector":"","trigger":"hover focus","delay":0,"container":"body"}}});</script>
</head>
<body class="html not-front not-logged-in no-sidebars page-broadbean-jobs">
  <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable">Skip to main content</a>
  </div>
    <header id="navbar" role="banner" class="navbar container navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="logo navbar-btn pull-left" href="/" title="Home">
        <img src="https://www.example.com/sites/default/files/example-logo.png" alt="Home" />
      </a>


      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <nav role="navigation">
                        <div class="region region-navigation">
    <section id="block-block-1" class="block block-block clearfix">


  <div class="jkInfoBlock"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <a href="tel:+61353329955">03 5332 9955</a></div>

</section>
  </div>
                              <ul class="menu nav navbar-nav"><li class="first collapsed"><a href="/employees/vacancies-and-employee-services" class="fa fa-search">Candidates</a></li>
<li class="collapsed"><a href="/employers/why-jk-personnel" class="fa-users fa">Employers</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/content/about-us" class="fa fa-info-circle">About Us</a></li>
<li class="last leaf"><a href="/content/contact-us" class="fa fa-phone-square">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>                            </nav>
      </div>
      </div>
</header>
<div class="main-container container">

  <div class="row">


    <section class="col-sm-12">
                  <a id="main-content"></a>
                                                                <div class="region region-content">
    <section id="block-system-main" class="block block-system clearfix">


  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                         <job>
                           <success>true</success>
             </job>
</section>
  </div>
    </section>


  </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer container">
    <div class="region region-footer">
    <section id="block-block-3" class="block block-block col-md-6 clearfix">


  <p>Copyright © 2018, JK Personnel | All Rights Reserved<br />
Website Planning, Production and Online Marketing by <a href="http://nbs.digital" target="_blank">NBS Digital</a></p>

</section>
<section id="block-menu-block-4" class="block block-menu-block col-md-6 clearfix">


  <div class="menu-block-wrapper menu-block-4 menu-name-menu-footer-menu parent-mlid-0 menu-level-1">
  <ul class="menu nav"><li class="first leaf menu-mlid-571"><a href="/content/timesheets">Timesheets</a></li>
<li class="leaf menu-mlid-572"><a href="/content/privacy-policy">Privacy</a></li>
<li class="leaf menu-mlid-573"><a href="/">Terms of Use</a></li>
<li class="leaf menu-mlid-574"><a href="/content/about-us">About Us</a></li>
<li class="last leaf menu-mlid-575"><a href="/content/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul></div>

</section>
  </div>
</footer>
  <script src="https://www.example.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js?pem64p"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**REQUIREMENT** : How to make sure the xml response sent through drupal using menu callback function is correct(right now it gives failure message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to output a raw response you need to `print` the value and exit instead of returning.

`print custom_changes_broadbean_interface_create(); // don't just return
exit;`